# List of taxonomy archive index page links

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I want to show  all my post taxonomies on the left side of the web page in such a way that when a person click on it the post can be displayed according to the taxonomies.is there anyway to display them and i also want to add some style in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a list using two functions: **`get_terms()`** and **`get_term_link()`**:

```
<?php
function wpse73271_get_term_archive_link_list( $taxonomy ) {
    // First, get an array of term IDs
    $term_objects = get_terms( $taxonomy );

    // Now, loop through $term_ids and get
    // an array of term archive permalinks
    foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {
        $term_object->url = get_term_link( $term_object, $taxonomy );
        $term_object->permalink = '<a href="' . $term_object->url . '">' . $term_object->name . '</a>';
    }

    // Now, build an HTML list of permalinks:
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {
        $output .= '<li>' . $term_object->permalink . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    // Now return the output
    return $output;
}
?>
```